# Why is my Google Drive CSS not showing up in Safari?

Tags: html, css, import

I used the `@import` at-rule, and it's located in the `<head>` of my HTML:

```
<style>
@import url('https://googledrive.com/host/0B4nfVqlTfnTzam45bnFnTXUyOEU');
</style>
```

This shows up in Firefox but not the latest version of Safari. Can anyone explain why? Is it because the file is in a Google Drive?

If it's just the actual CSS that's the problem, then I don't mind because it's only a test to see if the `@import` works, but is this method for importing style sheets good for most browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this should be a functioning method of linking styles to your website, it's not best practice.  It basically tells the browser that you are providing an internal style sheet, then tells it to import an external style sheet to nest within this element.  I wouldn't be surprised if this were to yield inconsistent results across different browsers.  Try skipping the  tags and including this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4nfVqlTfnTzam45bnFnTXUyOEU/yourfilename.css">
```

Now, you should consider implementing this method either way, but notice I also changed the file path.  Replace "`yourfilename.css`" with your style sheet's file name.  Even if the directory linked contains only one style sheet, you must explicitly define that file in order for the browser find it.